# @DataJpaTest how to specify repositories and entities to scan

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, spring-boot-test

By default `@DataJpaTest` scans all jpa repositories and `@Entity`. In my case I have 5 repositories package and 5 entities package. E.g

`com.acme.product.entity` is associated with 
`com.acme.product.repository`
`com.acme.users.entity` is associated with 
`com.acme.users.repository`
`com.acme.client.entity` is associated with 
`com.acme.client.repository`

And so on....

I would like to test each part in a separate classe. E.g.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@DataJpaTest
//Some configurations to import only product repositories and product entities
public class TestProductRepository {
  @Autowired
  TestEntityManager entityManager;
}
```

Note that I have configured 5 different `EntityManager` I would like to import them and use for example the `productEntityManager` in the `TestProductRepository` instead of the default `TestEntityManager` which loads all repositories/entites.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Why do you need the EntityManager if you have repositories?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli To override the default one: `TestEntityManager`. I just need a way to tell the `TestEntityManager` to use those repositories and entities.

Comment: But if you want test the ProductRepository you can inject it and don't need the entitymanager because this is configured

Comment: @SimonMartinelli You’re right but the problem is it slows the test because it scans all repositories and all entities.

Comment: I finally found a way to override the default `TestEntityManager` in the same wave the test time of each `@DataJpaTest` case was divided by 4.

Comment: Can you please provide this as the answer, that other users can view how you solved it? Thank you

Comment: Yes I’ll publish it

Comment: So @akuma8 how was it??

Comment: @Niccolò sorry, I was so busy that I forgot to post my answer. I'll do it tonight if I have time or this weekend. I'll let you know.

Comment: @Niccolò Sorry for this late answer, see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I manage to achieve what I wanted:

```
@ActiveProfiles( "dev" )
@RunWith( SpringRunner.class )
@DataJpaTest
// Exclude the default test database + the default EntityManager in purpose to use my configurations instead.
@AutoConfigureTestDatabase( connection = H2, replace = AutoConfigureTestDatabase.Replace.AUTO_CONFIGURED )
@Import( {
    ProductDataBaseConfig.class,//Import ProductEntityManager and other beans related to DB operations like TransactionManager, etc...
    ProductRepositoryContainer.class //Custom bean containing all product repositories
} )
public class TestProductRepository {
  @Autowired
  private TestEntityManager entityManager; 

}
```

The important thing here is the `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(...)` and `@Import(...)`, as I replaced the autoconfigured beans and import my own `ProductEntityManager` the `TestEntityManager` uses that provided configuration. 
This also reduce the scope of `@DataJpaTest` which does not scan all entities and repositories in the classpath and that was what I wanted.