How to unit test a small mysql table in a spring application
This is an education problem; I need to learn to wrap our JPA scripts in unit tests.
I fully expect JPA and Spring to already work correctly; I just need to learn to use it.
With "unit test" I mean "test the smallest possible unit of work", which in this case is:

sql script to create or modify the MySQL table
sql script to seed the database with legal values
java script with a JPA entity describing the field names and table name
java script with a JPA repository interface to define the queries

So a perfect unit test would

load the database connection
ignore ALL JPA entity classes except the ones used by this test
ignore ALL JPA repository classes except the ones used by this test
pre-compile the JPA queries, surfacing any query syntax problems
inject the test class with the repositories needed
run each test in the test class

Super easy; I just need to learn the syntax to make Spring and JPA load the correct subset of classes.
What needs to be tested is NOT if-statements; java is pretty good at interpreting if statements.
What needs to be tested IS

the ability for JPA to pre-compile the queries against the actual MySQL instance
the ability to load main tables and side tables correctly with the generated sql
the correctness of lower case field names, upper case table names, etc.
any errors of type N+1 that leads to catastrophic performance errors.

I want to make clear, we don't need unit tests for our if statements and class declarations. Java works correctly. We DO ABSOLUTELY need unit tests for the JPA declarations. JPA scripts rarely work correctly in the first few attempts.
It's a common source of misunderstanding, that all unit tests focus on one java class. This is one of all the many examples, where part of one unit is written in sql script, and part is written in java script, and they do not run independently; they are indeed one unit. The database is a part of the application code, not a separate entity.
Some sales people may believe that (or lie and say that) JPA will just connect "to any database". HAHAHAHA. No. Seriously, no. The same software engineers that write the MySQL scripts, also write the java JPA scripts, because it is the same application. And JPA is good, but not magical. A test abstracted away from the database will not uncover all our JPA script errors.
I tried to add tags to load the framework with a small mock application class
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = DatabaseDependencyApplication.class)
But this loads and compiles ALL the JPA repository interfaces (bad), but not all the JPA entities (makes pre-compiling crash because of missing entities).
If I could only specify the few JPA repositories to load, and if I could help it load the few needed JPA entities, then it might just work!
There is a different question asking about how to test a memory database, H2. I'm trying to test the queries generated for a physical database, MySQL. The JPA generated MySQL often fails at boot time, when  letter casing is a mismatch, GOOD, but sometimes at runtime, when side tables are not correctly de-serialized, VERY BAD, runtime error. I want to reduce the potential for all the runtime JPA errors, by detecting the most common ones in unit tests. Obviously, H2 does not necessarily surface issues with letter casing of the MySQL database or with side tables.

++Instead of bootstrapping the entire application context for every test, @DataJpaTest allows you to initialize only the parts of the Application context that are relevant to JPA tests.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52258838/datajpatest-how-to-specify-repositories-and-entities-to-scan

Does this answer your question? @DataJpaTest how to specify repositories and entities to scan
